# Labels not working on remote Mapserver installation

Tags: mapserver

I have Ubuntu 14.04/Mapserver7/apache2 installed on both my dev machine and on a remote server. As far as I can tell both installations are identical. For some reason labels are not showing up on the remote version. I built the mapserv executable on each installation with identical configurations so all the required libraries should be there. Any suggestions for troubleshooting?

MapServer version 7.0.0 OUTPUT=PNG OUTPUT=JPEG SUPPORTS=PROJ SUPPORTS=AGG SUPPORTS=FREETYPE SUPPORTS=CAIRO SUPPORTS=ICONV SUPPORTS=FRIBIDI SUPPORTS=WMS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WFS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WCS_SERVER SUPPORTS=FASTCGI SUPPORTS=GEOS INPUT=JPEG INPUT=POSTGIS INPUT=OGR INPUT=GDAL INPUT=SHAPEFILE

I have identical FONTS directory on each installation using truetype fonts. There are no errors showing in the mapserv error log.

It is servicing a WMS request.

Comment: Did you try shp2img setting the debug level? e.g. `shp2img -m your_map -o your_output -l your_layers -all_debug 3`. I guess other problem can be  the different access rights of the Apache user of the two machines.

Comment: Thank you, Zoltan.  So I got an error "agg2RenderBitmapGlyphs(): (null) invalid bitmap font size".  Looking in the source I found size must be between 0 and 4. When I set the text size to 4 (from 12) the text renders, but in a crude bitmap. Is this a default behavior when MS cannot find TTF fonts?

Comment: I still use version 6, but I have not met this restriction for font size. The documentation doesn't mention it: `Text size. Use a number to give the size in pixels of your TrueType font based label`. Did you set SYMBOLSCALEDENOM for the layer? It scales up/down the given font size.

Comment: I recompiled Mapserver again and now it is working.  Thank you for your help.